# Trying to get value out of a select option in the same form

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp

I'm trying to get value out of the select option. But it doesn't seems to be able to get since it's on form. How do I do it ? I mean by having taking the value out of the option select.

```
<strong>Select a product :</strong>
    <select name="stockid">
     <c:forEach var="row" items="${STOCKS1.rowsByIndex}">
      <option selected><c:out value="${row[0]}"/></option>
     </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </p>
<%!int query = 0; %>
 <%   
        if(request.getParameter("stockid") != null){
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/healthdb", "nbuser", "nbuser");

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select stockqty from stocks where stockid = ?");


            statement.setString(1,request.getParameter("stockid"));
            ResultSet resultset = 
                statement.executeQuery( ) ; 
        if(resultset.next()){
            out.print(resultset.getString("stockqty"));
            query = resultset.getInt("stockqty");
        }
 else
 out.print("lol");}%>
```

Comment: What's the schema type of `stockqty`? I don't think you can call `getString()` or `getInt()` arbitrarily for any type. You have to call the appropriate method that corresponds to the column type.

Comment: stockqty is int. When i do getstring it happens to be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.)** You can not select all the items in a select with `selected` ! Without `multiple="multiple"`

```
 <c:forEach var="row" items="${STOCKS1.rowsByIndex}">
  <option selected><c:out value="${row[0]}"/></option>
 </c:forEach>
```

E.g. `topFr[]`

```
<select name = "topFr[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option selected="selected">Peach</option>
</select>
```

if you can have multiple selected the `name` must be an array here `stockid[]`

```
<select name="stockid[]">
```

If you get from the `<Form>` an array you must treat `request.getParameter("stockid")`as an `array` !

**2.)**
**OR stockid = INT** then

You can not pass a string to a `field = INT`

if `stockid` is INT !

```
statement.setString(1,request.getParameter("stockid"));
```

will set a String to the query and the String will be **quoted**

wrong

```
select stockqty from stocks where stockid = "1"
```

you need

```
select stockqty from stocks where stockid = 1
```

Try

```
statement.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("stockid"));
```

also you should test with for empty !

```
String res = request.getParameter("stockid");
if(res != null && !res.isEmpty()){
```

Comment: @SabeehHasan : From OP's question we can see it is `Derby` :: `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/`